# web agent can redirect to the top target?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

I'm calling **from an iframe** an agent that should redirect the user to a given page on the whole page.

It's a lotus script agent that do his stuff and then redirect using a common:

```
Print "[http://www.server.com/db.nsf/simpleForm?OpenForm]"
```

How could I mention the TARGET (_top in my case) ?

thanks,

Comment: "it's **not** possible" is also an acceptable response :-). I already have a solution with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no better response had been given, I share my Javascript solution (comment welcome):

```
Print  |<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
window.top.location.href = "/myDB.nsf/MyFullRedirectedPage?OpenForm&L=|+lang+....+ |";
// -->
</script>
</head>
<body "style=\"margin:0 ; background:transparent\"">
processing... please wait!    N.B. this text will appear very short time.
</body>
</html>|
```

I put a background:transparent since I'm in a iframe.
I don't love this code almost flashing before the whole page is being refreshed.